# Python doctest with a loop

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

What if I need to do something line this inside the doctest:

```
'''
>>> for i in range(5):
        print i
'''
```

I get

```
    for i in range(5):
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Put it all one a single line?

Comment: Use `...` to lead the second and subsequent lines, as shown in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print i
```

What you showed has `print i` and the ellipsis (`...`) on separate lines.  Then doctest has no way to know that your code extends beyond the initial line; it looks for the ellipsis at the start of subsequent lines to know it's intended to be a multiline example.